# Why does program crash after exiting do-while loop asking for input in C?

Tags: c, string, input, do-while, string-length

I am having trouble with correctly using a do-while loop to keep asking for another string if the one input is longer than what you want. After entering a string which is too big the program expects another but after I input an acceptable one the programs crashes instead of exiting normally, why is that? This is only part of the code of a larger program. Also, I am relatively new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_MAX 100

int main()
{
    //Declaration of variables
    char  temp_input[STRING_MAX];

    //Read input
    do
    {
        scanf("%s", temp_input);
    }while(strlen(temp_input)>STRING_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

thanks for all the help guys!!

Comment: Do you understand what `strlen()` does?

Comment: yes it returns the length of the string input doesnt it? @iharob

Comment: Exactly, how could that be `>STRING_MAX`?

Comment: oh yeah.. but how does it loop around then when i enter a string longer than that?

Comment: `scanf` doesn't care. It's happy to write 150 characters into a 100-character buffer, after which *anything* the program does is purely a matter of chance. You have no right to expect any particular behavior once you've overwritten memory.

Comment: `strlen()` counts the number of characters in a c string, it could be implemented like this `size_t strlen(const char *const str) {size_t count = 0; while (*str++ != '\0') count++; return count;}` so you see, there is no check for boundaries except for the terminating `'\0'` which tells `strlen()` that this is the end of the string, in your code, both `strlen()` and `scanf()` are accessing the array beyond bounds.

Comment: @ Weather Vane Yes, `scanf()` is not a robust method for OP: removed.

Comment: @chux and `fgets()` has the same problem.

Comment: @Weather Vane, True, yet I find `fgets()` easier to control as suggested in the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think this is what you actually want

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_MAX 10

int main (void)
{
    char         string[STRING_MAX];
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int total;
    int          chr;

    do {
        count = 0;
        total = 0;
        while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'))
        {
            if (count < STRING_MAX - 1)
                string[count++] = chr;
            total += 1;
        }
        string[count] = '\0';
    } while (total > STRING_MAX - 1);
    printf("The input string was:\n\t%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of checking that chr is not EOF? i also tried the following condition and it seems to work just as fine.
while ((chr = getchar()) != '\n')
is it for the case that we read the string from a file?

Comment: If you press Ctrl+D on linux or Ctrl+Z on windows the input stream will be closed and `getchar()` will return `EOF`.

Comment: oh ok didnt know that.. so its not vital for the code to work then?

Comment: It's not hurting it either but no, the code will work as long as you compare `chr` to `'\n'` which actually flushes the charaters.

Comment: i just noticed chr is declared as int, shouldnt it be char? it works but why? @iharob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72186/discussion-between-yiannis-and-iharob).

Answer (score 1):

Code is failing as `scanf("%s", temp_input);` does not prevent excessive long input from overfilling `temp_input` resulting in undefined behavior (UB)

`fgets()` alternative:

```
char buf[STRING_MAX];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
  // if input does not end with \n, assume additional char for this line.
  if (strchr(buf, '\n') == NULL) {
    int ch;
    // Get extra char and throw away.
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
      ; 
  }

  // do something with buf - get rid of potential trailing \n, then print
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
  puts(buf);  // this also prints a \n

  // now get next line
}
```

Comment: the "Get extra char and throw away" part is superfluous, isn't it? `fgets()` always reads until newline if there's a newline…

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant.  `fgets()` stops earlier for various reasons, including a full buffer - even if additional reads would discover the `'\n'`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant `fgets()` reads the max number of chars it is told to read, and leaves any more in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getchar()` to read from stdin.  It gets one char at a time so you can break if string is to long.  Maybe you want somting like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_MAX 100

int main()
{
    //Declaration of variables
    char  temp_input[STRING_MAX];
    int ch;  // char just read
    int ins; // insert point

    //Read input
    ins = 0; // start at begining
    for(;;)
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if( ch == 13 ) // return char
        {
            temp_input[ins] = 0; // null terminate string
            break;
        }
        temp_input[ins] = ch;
        ins++; // move up next insert point
        if( ins == STRING_MAX )
        {
            temp_input[STRING_MAX-1] = 0; // null terminate;
            break;  // at end of string
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Why use 13 when code should use `'\n'` which usually has the value of 10?  This code also has issue when `ch == EOF`.

Comment: but this doesnt allow another input does it? it just cuts off at 99?

Comment: @Yiannis I am sorry but how you get input without overflowing the buffer has nothing to do with doing it again, just write a function and call it the number of times you wish.

Comment: @Yianis you want to keep reading until the user inputs less or exaclty that number of characters?

Comment: @iharob yes that is what i want :)

Answer (score -1):

You're causing a *buffer overflow*, don't use `scanf` for this purpose.

Comment: is there any way i can deal with the buffer overflow and still use scanf? if not what should i use? fgets? getchar?

Comment: @Yiannis To prevent buffer overflow with `scanf()` you need to tell `scanf()` how many characters to read, for example in your case `scanf("%99s", temp_input)`. But you need to know that `scanf()` will stop reading when a space character is found in the stream with the `"%s"` specifier, so it's probably not what you want.

Comment: yes but that wouldnt allow for another input.. so its not possible with scanf then?

Comment: @Yiannis Why wouldn't that allow for another input? what are you trying?

Comment: if i use scanf("%99s", temp_input) then what would be the condition in the while loop? since scanf would only read 99 + termination character?

Comment: Why would you need a `while` loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72171/discussion-between-yiannis-and-iharob).